# How can I lead to 404 Page Not Found when View page has no result?

Tags: views, 6

How can I lead to 404 Page Not Found when View page has no result?

I tried this code from http://drupal.org/node/1295824#comment-5192868in "empty text" but the View page still exist with only page title eve if it has not result to list.

```
<?php
drupal_set_header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`drupal_not_found()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_not_found/6) function. It sets the correct headers, omits blocks from the page output to conserve CPU and bandwidth, and is the correct way to set a 404 through code in Drupal.

Also see [`drupal_access_denied()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/6) which might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`drupal_goto()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6) to redirect and set a proper status code.