# Views: add custom no result behavior to a view?

Tags: views

I am trying to add custom no result behaviour to a view. I have many pages with view panes in them. Sometimes if no results are available, I would like to be able to display a 404. This is not an option when it's a view pane. I would like to do this in a reusable way where if the view pane has that custom option then this happens.

I can hard code this stuff on one of views hook, but ideally I want to be able to configure such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an option in views panes because a 404 should be returned by the page_callback handler, which in this case is the panel that is holding the pane.

Option 1, see if this module works [views404](https://www.drupal.org/project/views404), but I have not used it so I do not know for sure.

Option 2, use [drupal_not_found()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32329/how-can-i-lead-to-404-page-not-found-when-view-page-has-no-result), though I have not tried this in a panel.  Or if you are using contextual filters [try this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/how-do-i-set-my-views-to-return-a-404-using-global-null-under-contextual-filter).

Option 3, stop using panels and use view page with Bean and Context and theme regions and a bunch of other things. This way the page_callback is being handled by the view, so the view has the authority to return a 404 instead of theming the frame and other blocks and presenting those.  Downside is you have to restructure the whole site so you probably dont want that.